# Problema resgatar References de uma consulta no Nhibernate HasMany

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Estou utilizando o Nhibernate com WebAPI
tenho 2 entidades Perfil e PessoaLogin 
Pessoalogin pode ter N Perfil
e Perfil 1 Pessoa Login. Porém, quando vou consultar no webservice PessoaLogin a referencia    Perfil só funciona se for NULL se eu adicionar um Perfil, sempre que    for consultar PessoaLogin da Erro. Vou descrever aqui o codigo

---

Perfil.cs

```
  public class Perfil
{



    public Perfil()
    {

        PessoaLogin = new Collection<PessoaLogin>();

    } 

    public virtual int IdPerfil { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PessoaLogin> PessoaLogin { get; set; }
}
```

PerfilMap.cs

```
  public class PerfilMap : ClassMap<Perfil>
{
    public PerfilMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.IdPerfil);

        Map(x => x.Descricao)
        .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);

        HasMany(x => x.PessoaLogin)
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .KeyColumn("Id_Perfil");



        Table("Perfil");
    }

}
```

PessoaLogin.cs

```
 public class PessoaLogin:Pessoa
{

    public virtual string Senha { get; set; }

    public virtual Perfil Perfil { get; set; }

}
```

PessoaLoginMap.cs

```
   public PessoaLoginMap()
    {

        KeyColumn("IdPessoa");

        Map(x => x.Senha)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(MapLength.TextoMini);

        References(x => x.Perfil)
            .Columns("id_Perfil");

        Table("PessoaLogin");


    }


}
```

O quando vou consultar o webservice

se PessoaLogin.Perfil for Null aparece normalmente
exemplo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora se eu Adicionar um Perfil quando for requisitar o PessoaLogin 
me da a seguinte mensagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

WebAPiConfig.cs

```
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

PessoaLoginController.cs

```
public class PessoaLoginController : ApiController
{

    private IPessoaLoginRepository _repository44;

    public PessoaLoginController()
    {
        _repository44 = new PessoaLoginRepository();

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
    {
        //var list = _repository44.GetAll11();
        var lists = _repository44.GetAll();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lists);
    }

    [HttpGet] 
    public HttpResponseMessage GetById(int id)
    {
        var acesso = _repository44.Get(id);

        if (acesso == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, acesso);
    }




    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(string nome, string senha)
    {
        var obj = _repository44.ValidarLogin(nome, senha);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Incluir([FromBody] PessoaLogin pessoalogin)
    {
        pessoalogin = _repository44.Add(pessoalogin);

        if (pessoalogin != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, pessoalogin);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Deu o Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não há nada de errado neste comportamento. O que você gostaria que aparecesse?

Comment: Olá Cigano gostaria de pegar o ID da referencia. ---- [{ "id": "1", "Senha":"323232", "Perfil": 1, "IdPessoa":1, "Nome":"JOEL SANTANA"}]   ----

Comment: Você quer que serialize apenas estes campos, certo?

Comment: Ele só funciona se for NULL se no Banco eu setar o IdPerfil do PessoaLogin como NULL ele me aparece correto. caso contrario da esse bug no JSON dai não consigo restagar esse PessoaLogin.Perfil

Comment: Isso esse Campo Perfil sem dar aquele erro.

Comment: O que você está usando pra devolver o JSON pelo Controller? Pode editar sua pergunta colocando esta parte?

Comment: WebApiConfig.css /        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

Comment: PessoaLoginController.css /    [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
        {
            //var list = _repository44.GetAll11();
            var lists = _repository44.GetAll();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lists);

            


        }

Comment: Repository.css /   public IList<T> GetAll()
        {



            return _connection.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>();
           
            

        }

Comment: Me disseram que pode ser loop infinito quando eu requisito esse Metodo GetAll, dai segui alguns tutoriais para inserir aquele bloco de codigo no WebApiConfig.css só que mesmo esta zicado a referencia

Comment: Por favor, coloque os códigos **na sua pergunta**, e não como comentários. Vou responder.

Comment: Postado........

Answer (score 1):

Você está serializando um proxy, conforme este código em comentário. Não há nada de errado em como o serializador resolve o problema. A redução das propriedades serializadas é que é o foco da questão:

```
[HttpGet] 
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll() 
{ 
    var lists = _repository44.GetAll(); 
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lists);
}
```

A solução é implementar um resolvedor de contratos que serialize o objeto usando a definição da classe, e não do proxy:

```
public class NHibernateContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver {
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType) {
        if (typeof(INHibernateProxy).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)) {
            return base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType.BaseType);
        } else {
            return base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);
        }
    }
}
```

Ao configurar o serializador, passe para ele o resolvedor de contratos (última linha):

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter; 
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects; 
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter); 
json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =  Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new NHibernateContractResolver();
```

Comment: Segui suas informações agora deu erro  type failed to serialize the response body for content type

Comment: Olá Cigano na sua resposta eu coloquei o resultado da aplicação. abs Valeu

Comment: @DanielMachado Você está usando o site todo errado. Sugiro que leia os tópicos de ajuda antes de sair alterando respostas. Sua edição foi anulada. Estou colocando na pergunta.